# How do I send connection objects using Pipe() in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, operating-system, multiprocessing

I am not able to send pipe objects between processes.

```
pipe_i.send(diff_connection_object)
```

I know connection objects are not pickalable. As send() only takes as argument picklable objects thus I am not able to send the connection object. So how can I do this ?

Comment: What error do you get? Please add the traceback.

Comment: The same error as in the reply by Mike Mckerns

Answer (score 1):

If you use a fork of `multiprocessing` called `multiprocess` then it should work for almost any connection object you want to send.  The fork uses `dill` instead of `pickle`, to provide better serialization.  For example, here's a `sqlite3.Connection` object.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x1046134b8>
>>> import multiprocess
>>> p1,p2 = multiprocess.Pipe()
>>> p1.send(c)
>>> c_ = p2.recv()
>>> c_
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x104af8200>
```

It's unclear which connection object is **the** connection object being asked about.  So here's a `_multiprocess.Connection` object being passed with the `Pipe` from `multiprocess`.

```
>>> c = p1.__class__ 
>>> p1.send(c)
>>> c_ = p2.recv()
>>> c_
<type '_multiprocess.Connection'>
```

However, in trying to pass the `_multiprocess.Connection` object instance, instead of the `_multiprocess.Connection` object class… the `send` works just fine, but the `recv` will unfortunately fail to unpickle the object.

```
>>> p3,p4 = multiprocess.Pipe()
>>> p1.send(p3)
>>> p3_ = p2.recv()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 259, in loads
    return load(file)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.5.dev0-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 249, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1089, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
>>>
```

If the last case worked, you could do some pretty cool stuff, I think.  Maybe it's worth submitting a ticket to `dill` or `multiprocess`, and requesting it work?

Comment: But I wasn't able to pass the object to the class 'class multiprocessing.Connection' .

Comment: ??? -- Neither `multiprocessing` nor `multiprocess` has `Connection` at the top of the namespace, as far as I can tell.  Can you give more info on what you are asking, specifically which `connection` objects?

Comment: [connection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection) object for Pipe() communication between processes.[multiprocessing.pipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue you're suffering from is a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue4892) which has been fixed in Python 3.

My suggestion is to open the connection on the child process instead of the parent one. Another way consists in opening the connection on the parent process before spawning the new child and passing the connection via inheritance.

These are anyway more correct approaches rather than passing stateful objects across pipes.